# site for uploading our code of our games

Tags: java, project-hosting

Is there any site for uploading our code of the games which have written by ourselves?
thanks

ps: also it is better that the site send some feedback!

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole bunch of project hosting sites for open source projects, whose community rules and general atmosphere are different. Here's a few:

1. [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)
2. [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/)
3. [github](http://github.com/)

Pick one you like or just google for "project hosting" or something along those lines for many more.

Answer (score 2):

Can you be a bit more specific? I mean, there's:

- [Google Code](http://code.google.com)
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net)
- [GitHub](http://github.com/)

...and probably a couple of dozen more, but those are the first three that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://github.com/ for Git repositories or http://bitbucket.org/ for Mercurial repositories.